# How do I do an update and a delete to an entity within a single call to SubmitChanges()

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext

```
var dc = new DataContext();
var myItem = dc.Items.Single(x => x.Id == 12);

myItem.LastModifiedBy = "me";
myItem.LastModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
// dc.SubmitChanges(); I don't want to do this!

dc.DeleteOnSubmit(myItem);
dc.SubmitChanges(); // does not perform the update
```

I made a change to myItem, and I want that change to be made to the database, for auditing purposes. I don't want to call SubmitChanges() twice. I want this to happen in a single call to SubmitChanges(), to take advantage of the implicit transaction. How can I tell the DataContext to do both the update and the delete? The code only does the delete. I know the update is not called because the database table's update trigger doesn't fire. The DataContext probably thinks that since it's marked for deletion, there's no point bothering with the update.

Any suggestions? Ideally, it would mean not having to use a stored procedure. Also, I am not able, for various reasons, to use TransactionScope.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining a scenario where it makes sense to update an item and immediately delete it. Just for my own edification, can you hint at a use case?

Comment: We have triggers that run on updates, inserts and deletes, and record what changed. Each table has LastModifiedBy. If you delete, you get the LastModifiedBy from when it was last modified, which could have been ages ago. So by doing an update first, and updating the LastModifiedBy value, the trigger can record get the LastModifiedBy value from the deleted item, and then we know who did the delete.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER [Item_DeleteTrigger] ON [dbo].[Item] 
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @auditLogID INT;

 INSERT INTO AuditLog (ObjectName, Identifier, AuditAction, CreatedBy, CreatedDateTime)
 SELECT 'Item', itemId, 'DEL', LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedDateTime
 FROM deleted;

 SELECT @auditLogID = @@IDENTITY;

 INSERT INTO AuditLogEntry (AuditLogID, PropertyName, OldValue, NewValue)
 SELECT @auditLogID, 'ItemId', ItemId, null
 FROM deleted; END

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best solution to this problem would be to change the DELETE trigger to insert the proper `DateTime`, and skip doing the extra needless update altogether.